# Can we connect Cassandra DB with karate framework?

Tags: cassandra, karate

I'm working on an API service which is using a Cassandra database connection. Is there a way to connect Cassandra db in Karate framework?

I'm familiar with the ways to connect oracle and postgreSql databases with Karate, but unable to find a method for Cassandra.

Comment: you can do ANYTHING in Karate as long as you are willing to write (one time) some Java "glue" code. refer to this other example for more ideas: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to build a Java app that connects to Cassandra using the [Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/). You can then call your Java code from Karate (see [Calling Java in Karate](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-java) for an example).

Here's some minimal code to help you get started with the Java driver:

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.Row;

public class HelloCassandra {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()
      .withKeyspace("keyspace_name")
      .build()) {
        // Select the release_version from the system.local table:
        ResultSet rs = session.execute("SELECT release_version FROM system.local");
        Row row = rs.one();
        //Print the results of the CQL query to the console:
        if (row != null) {
          System.out.println(row.getString("release_version"));
        } else {
          System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        }
      }
      System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

You'll need to add this in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can [get a full example `pom.xml` here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/connecting-to-your-database-with-the-datastax-java-driver.html#_example_pom_xml_file). Cheers!